# USB wiped itself but still showing that its full?

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure

My Data saved from laptop to usb, and then I pulled it out, then something popped up on the screen saying that it was full and that I needed to delete stuff, so I put the USB back in and went to computer and all to go into it and when I did it isn't showing anything on the usb but when I go to computer it still shows that the usb is full. Does anybody know what is going on ? How can I get my data again?

Comment: You can run a `chkdsk \f` through command line to fix anything wrong on your USB.

Comment: Also you can try `attrib -r -s -h USB:` where USB is your drive letter.

Comment: @avirk I will try the attrib-r-s-h USB, thanks for the solution

Comment: Also try the first solution too. Sometimes something went wrong and disk gone erroneous so we can fix it by run that command. If you are going to check it now I will wait your response.

Comment: The correct command is `chkdsk X: /f`, where X: is the drive letter of your USB device. Please take note of the direction of the slash.

Comment: @avirk I will try now

Comment: @RandolphWest thanks! I typed it mistakenly and I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @avirk I do not get a clue

Comment: It is unlikely that all the files suddenly have hidden attribute set.  The `chkdsk` is the first thing to do.  Did you "unplug safely"?

Comment: @RandolphWest this is what I can
The type of the file system is FAT32.
Volume FLASDISK created 5/12/2012 10:08 PM
Volume Serial Number is 21C9-9E4B
Windows is verifying files and folders...
File and folder verification is complete.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.
    7,954,404 KB total disk space.
            4 KB in 1 hidden files.
            8 KB in 2 folders.
      618,908 KB in 4 files.
    7,335,480 KB are available.

        4,096 bytes in each allocation unit.
    1,988,601 total allocation units on disk.
    1,833,870 allocation units available on disk.

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Comment: @Paul, when I unplug the usb in the scanning process and the process is not running, my usb end off by force

Comment: Is there anything important on your USB which you don't want to lose? If not then you can format it through command prompt.

Comment: @avirk, certainly there, i'm is students, and in my USB there are some tasks that I did not copy to my laptop, so I ask here? thanks before for the solution

Comment: Have you tried the `attrib` and `chkdsk` yet or not?

Comment: @avirk, I tried the chkdsk

Comment: And attrib command what about that?

Comment: Download [Icare](http://www.icare-recovery.com/recover-data-from-formatted-drive.html) and check if it can see your data on USB and then you can download [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the files.

Comment: @avirk oh, ok it seems to be very helpful. thank you master

Answer (score 0):

The USB drive is empty. Based on your comments above, I would assume that the copy was not even started because the copy process calculated that there wasn't enough space on the drive.

You'll just have to start the copy process again, and make sure you copy less data than there is space on the USB drive.

Comment: well I've done it, but I'm confused as to why the problem could arise? what due to system error, or because the virus

Comment: It was not a virus or a system error. It was a combination of your quickness to remove the drive, combined with the calculation for disk space showing as insufficient, happening at the same time.

Comment: well thanks, to her the notice. very helpful for me to understand more about the problem
usb wiped itself, but still showing that its full

Comment: Well, if it says full in the drive properties. It might be a virus. It is commonplace. A virus waits for a plug and play device and instantly "hides" your data. The attrib -r -s -h USB solution solves this.